# Did the "30 Days of Night" vampires have an invitation?

Tags: plot-explanation, 30-days-of-night

It is pretty standard vampire lore that in order for a vampire to be able to come into a home or even a town, they have to be invited. In [30 Days of Night](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0389722/), however, I don't remember there being any sort of invitation and the vampires seem pretty free to come and go into the houses and the town as they please.

I'm willing to accept that not all vampire tales have to follow the same rules, and in fact there are many differing aspects to them such as how they are affected by sunlight. Another traditional theme however that 30 Days does comply with is that the vampire(s)' coming tends to be preceded by a human thrall who is sent to prepare the way for them (Renfield in Dracula, or Ben Foster's character in 30 Days).

**So I'm curious if the "invitation" element was simply omitted from the 30 Days version of vampires or if I just missed it somehow.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in the movie universe they didn't have to.

From [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0389722/faq#.2.1.21)

> ...However, other rules such being repelled by crosses, holy water, or garlic does not seem to apply here, nor does the rule of vampires not entering a person's home without an invitation..

Also worth mentioning that the movie was praised for abandon a lot of the tired out vampires movies cliches.

[For example](http://www.nola.com/movies/index.ssf/2007/10/30_days_of_night_a_bloody_good.html)

> Scrapping many of the undead cliches -- including trading the whole blood-sucking thing for a much more frantic, and messy, brand of dining -- and aided by troublingly realistic special effects, Slade has crafted one hell of a monster movie.
>
> That's saying a lot, since so many vampire films seem to end up treading the same old ground. But **there are no garlic cloves here, no stakes in the heart, no evil-repelling crosses**. Aside from vampires' aversion to sunlight and thirst for blood, Slade -- in a story based on the comic by Steve Niles and Ben Templesmith -- has pretty much **rewritten the whole  vampire rule book.**